# Probability of significant result is due to chance hypothesis testing

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing

So in principle, a statistically significant result is not attributed to chance.

I'm given 70 independent experiments on the number of actions of 500 customers over a course of a month. Each experiment is on the same set of 500 customers, but it is believed that their number of actions will increase over time.

I'm given the sample mean and alpha, and I was able to calculate the p value. Now I'm asked to find the probability that I find some significant results just due to chance.

Can someone explain to me what should I do in this case with the information I have so far?

**EDIT:**
$H_0 = 49.75$, $H_a \ge 49.75$, $\alpha = 0.05$

I'm using $t$ test and Python `scipy.stats as st`

```
alpha = 0.05
ttest = st.ttest_1samp(data, 49.75)
pval = ttest[1]

if (pval > alpha):
   significant = 1
```

Comment: It is not forbidden to show what you have done so far. How did you get the p-value, for instance?

Comment: So I just run a z test for each experiment, then get the p value from the z test statistic @callculus

Comment: Ok, nice and very short description. But what is so difficult to show what you´ve calculated? You expect that we make some effort when we´re answering. I think we can expect the same from you. And it is not clear as well what you´re asked for.

Comment: I'm not deliberately trying to hide my work or anything. I'm using Python for this and the test would be a few lines of code. I'll edit my original post as soon as I get back home.
I'm just asking for some explanation on MCS but I don't expect people to do all the work for me here

Comment: I´m looking forward to your edit. No matter if you use Python or not, you should have needed a null hypothesis and an alternative hypothesis.  Hypothesis testing is not just putting in some numbers. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing#The_testing_process)

Comment: @callculus I just edited my post. I also used a t test instead of a z test.